# How do I migrate from the Google Profiles and Provisioning API to the Admin SDK Directory API?

Tags: google-admin-sdk, google-provisioning-api, google-profiles-api

The Google Profiles API and Provisioning API are scheduled to be shut down on April 20, 2015 and I need to migrate my code to use the Admin SDK Directory API instead. How do I go about this migration?

Answer (score -1):

Refer to the [migration guide](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/migrate) determine you how to translate calls to the Profiles API and Provisioning API to their corresponding calls in the Admin SDK Directory API API. Refer to the Admin SDK Directory API's documentation for information on how to download libraries and get started.

Be aware that support for older authorization methods ([ClientLogin](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/AuthForInstalledApps), [AuthSub](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/AuthSub), and [OAuth 1.0](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth_ref)) are also scheduled to be shut down at the same time. If you are currently using these methods please also migrate to [OAuth2](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2) at the same time.